# Oracle sql how to join small number of rows with larger number of rows and not repeat small rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to join a table with a small number of rows with one with a larger number of rows and not repeat the small table's rows.

For example:

```
people:
person_id name
--------- ----
1         Dave
2         Sam 

jobs:
job_id change_date person_id 
------ ----------- ---------
1      01-01-2013  1      
2      01-01-2014  1
3      01-01-2013  2
4      01-01-2014  2

select p.name,
       j.job_id,
       j.change_date
from   people p,
       jobs   j
where  j.person_id = p.person_id
```

Returns:

```
name job_id change_date
---- ------ -----------
Dave 1      01-01-2013
Dave 2      01-01-2014
Sam  3      01-01-2013
Sam  4      01-01-2014
```

I want:

```
name job_id change_date
---- ------ -----------
Dave 1      01-01-2013
     2      01-01-2014
Sam  3      01-01-2013
     4      01-01-2014
```

Is this possible using Oracle SQL?

Comment: You can retrieve NULLS instead of repeated names but why do you need that?

Comment: Because users like things to look like Excel, not like unformatted data.

Comment: Here is the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26768447/problems-with-grouping

Comment: Here are a few thoughts: Probably you won't give your users SQL Developer or Toad to get the data, but a program written in a programming language or a report engine instead. These can easily display the data in whatever fashion you want (suppress data as required above or toggle the background color on user change or draw a thick line, whatever ...) SQL is usually mainly for supplying the data. But yes, you can use a window analytic function such as row_number or lag/lead in order to recognize repeating values and suppress them. By the way: people.name is unique, I suppose/hope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row_number can be used to get sequence number an then case can be used to give empty name for person name for sequence >1

Also changed it to use explicit join

```
   Select ( case when seq=1 then name else '' end ) as name,
       job_id,
       Change_date
   From (
      Select p.name,
          j.job_id,
          j.change_date,
         Row_number() over ( partition by p.person_id order by job_id desc) as seq
      from   people p
      Join jobs j
     On j.person_id = p.person_id) T
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when row_number() over (partition by p.name order by j.change_date) = 1 then p.name else NULL end as name,
       j.job_id,
       j.change_date
from   people p,
       jobs   j
where  j.person_id = p.person_id
order by p.name, j.change_date;
```

You may use an analytic function ROW_NUMBER to numerate the same names and show a name only for the first. But you need to order your results.